# Accessing Firestore via Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

So i have 2 Cloud Functions within the same file:

```
exports.Auth = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onRequest((req, res) =>
```

and

```
exports.IPN = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onRequest((req, res) =>
```

When adding the following code right at the start of my Auth function it adds a new document to the Firestore as expected, however, when i add the same code at the start of my IPN function, which is currently being called via Paypal's IPN Simulator, it does nothing, no errors.

```
  let pin = RandomPIN(10, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
  var userRef = db.collection('Users').doc(pin);
  var setWithOptions = userRef.set({ Activated: false }, { merge: true });
  console.log("PIN: "+pin);
```

What on earth is going on, i must be missing something?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

Here are the logs, first with the 2 middle lines commented and then uncommented [image] It seems to be silently failing, i'm just not sure what is causing it.

**Update with Complete function:**

```
exports.IPN = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onRequest((req, res) =>
{
  console.log("IPN Notification Event Received");

  let pin = RandomPIN(10, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
  var userRef = db.collection('Users').doc(pin);
  var setWithOptions = userRef.set({ Activated: false }, { merge: true });
  console.log("PIN: "+pin);

  if (req.method !== "POST")
  {
    console.error("Request method not allowed.");
    res.status(405).send("Method Not Allowed");
  }
  else
  {
    console.log("IPN Notification Event received successfully.");
    res.status(200).end();
  }

  let ipnTransactionMessage = req.body;
  // Convert JSON ipn data to a query string since Google Cloud Function does not expose raw request data.
  let formUrlEncodedBody = querystring.stringify(ipnTransactionMessage);
  // Build the body of the verification post message by prefixing 'cmd=_notify-validate'.
  let verificationBody = `cmd=_notify-validate&${formUrlEncodedBody}`;

  console.log(`Verifying IPN: ${verificationBody}`);

  let options = {
    method: "POST",
    uri: getPaypalURI(),
    body: verificationBody,
  };

  // POST verification IPN data to paypal to validate.
  request(options, function callback(error, response, body)
  {
    if(!error && response.statusCode === 200)
    {
      if(body === "VERIFIED")
      {
        console.log(`Verified IPN: IPN message for Transaction ID: ${ipnTransactionMessage.txn_id} is verified.`);
        SendPIN(ipnTransactionMessage.payer_email, pin);
      }
      else if(body === "INVALID")
        console.error(`Invalid IPN: IPN message for Transaction ID: ${ipnTransactionMessage.txn_id} is invalid.`);
      else
        console.error("Unexpected reponse body.");
    }
    else
    {
      console.error(error);
      console.log(body);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: "which is currently being called via Paypal's IPN Simulator" Are you sure the function is actually being called?

Comment: Yup, it verifies simulated transactions just fine if i comment out the middle 2 firestore lines

Comment: Please add this information to your question, so we can clean up the comments trail.

Comment: Do you return the Promise returned by the `set()` method? You should add the entire code of the function to your question, it may be because you don't return and chain the different promises.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the entire function that doesn't work the way you expect, not just a few lines of it.

Comment: Sorry to leave the question hanging guys, I'm fairly sure it's a promise chaining issue as Renaud alluded to, i'm completely new to all this so i'm just trying to get my head around it. Once I've figured it out i'll update.

Comment: I have updated my question with the complete function @DougStevenson Is it the case that my function is finishing execution before the firestore set completes, due to the res.status(200).end(); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it is a problem of Promises chaining and also a problem due to the `request` library: `request` supports callback interfaces natively but does not return a promise, which is what you must do within a Cloud Function.

I would suggest that you watch these official Firebase videos from Doug : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA&t=28s and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=652XeeKNHSk which explain this key concept.

You can use `request-promise` (https://github.com/request/request-promise) and the `rp()` method which "returns a regular Promises/A+ compliant promise".

It is not clear what `SendPIN()` is doing. Let's make the assumption it returns a Promise. If this is true, you could adapt your code along the following lines:

```
//....
const rp = require('request-promise');
//....

exports.IPN = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  console.log('IPN Notification Event Received');

  let pin = RandomPIN(
    10,
    '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
  );
  var userRef = db.collection('Users').doc(pin);

  if (req.method !== 'POST') {
    console.error('Request method not allowed.');
    res.status(405).send('Method Not Allowed');
  } else {
    let ipnTransactionMessage;
    userRef
      .set({ Activated: false }, { merge: true })
      .then(() => {
        console.log('PIN: ' + pin);
        ipnTransactionMessage = req.body;
        // Convert JSON ipn data to a query string since Google Cloud Function does not expose raw request data.
        let formUrlEncodedBody = querystring.stringify(ipnTransactionMessage);
        // Build the body of the verification post message by prefixing 'cmd=_notify-validate'.
        let verificationBody = `cmd=_notify-validate&${formUrlEncodedBody}`;

        console.log(`Verifying IPN: ${verificationBody}`);

        let options = {
          method: 'POST',
          uri: getPaypalURI(),
          body: verificationBody
        };
        // POST verification IPN data to paypal to validate.
        return rp(options);
      })
      .then(response => {
        //Not sure what you will get within the response object...
        console.log(
          `Verified IPN: IPN message for Transaction ID: ${
            ipnTransactionMessage.txn_id
          } is verified.`
        );
        return SendPIN(ipnTransactionMessage.payer_email, pin); //It is not clear what SendPIN is doing, let's make the assumption it returns a Promise...
      })
      .then(() => {
        res.send('Success');
        return null;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(
          `Invalid IPN: IPN message for Transaction ID: ${
            ipnTransactionMessage.txn_id
          } is invalid.`
        );
        res
          .status(500)
          .send(
            'Error: ' +
              err +
              ` - Invalid IPN: IPN message for Transaction ID: ${
                ipnTransactionMessage.txn_id
              } is invalid.`
          );
        return null;
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the links and your help Renaud, SendPIN is just a void function that uses nodemailer to email the pin. I'm not sure if it's related but i get an error @ res.send('Success'); "error  Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return"

Comment: Is SendPIN asynchronous and returning a Promise?

Comment: No, it's just a synchronous void function *function SendPIN(email, pin)* it just calls *nodemailer.createTransport* and then *transporter.sendMail*

Comment: Are you sure it is not asynchronous?  See https://nodemailer.com/usage/: "If callback argument is not set then the method returns a Promise object. Nodemailer itself does not use Promises internally but it wraps the return into a Promise for convenience."

Comment: I've modified the answer by adding `return null;` after `res.send('Success');`. However, I am not 100% sure it is the best way to solve the problem you mentioned. It would be interesting to have the opinion of Doug or Frank on this point.

Comment: With return null; it gets past eslint but crashes, here is the log https://i.imgur.com/N9gS9bi.png. I was hoping this narrow area of my project would be trivial, given the example code available. This promise chaining stuff has got me in a pickle, i keep thinking i have it but it never works, arghh.

Comment: When an IPN comes through and is VERIFIED + payment_status=Completed, i just need to create a firestore document with the name of a newly generated PIN and then email the PIN, this is much more difficult than i anticipated, or am i just going about it the wrong way? Please send help Doug/Frank

Comment: It works! Thank you very much for your time. I suppose i had better put the time in understanding all of this *then then then then* with a sprinkle of request-promise gibberish, should i need to update it in the future.